# Can we do eager loading with joins?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I know that `includes` eager load all associated model attributes, for example the following:

```
@posts = Post.includes(:user)
```

will load all posts with all user attributes (name, birthe_date, login ....) for each post

And if i'm right we can't use select with includes to fetch just some attributes like this :

```
@posts = Post.includes(:user).select("posts.*, user.name as user_name")
```

so, with joins it's possible to use select :

```
posts = Post.joins(:user).select("posts.*, user.name as user_name")
```

my question is : when i use `select` within `joins`, can we call this an `eager loading` ?

if so, is

```
posts = Post.joins(:user).select("posts.*, user.*")
```

equivalent to ? :

```
posts = Post.includes(:user)
```

Comment: May I ask the purpose of your question? Might help create a good answer for you :)

Comment: @RichPeck i added examples to be more clear :)

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/181-include-vs-joins

Comment: Thanks for updated examples! Being honest, I am not exactly sure about the mechanics of these two query-types, but I added a reference to a RailsCast which demonstrates how they work for you

Comment: I was asking because I wanted to load some data on top of my original query, and I ended up using a select query on the association, which I thought you may require too

Comment: @RichPeck thank you, i have already seen the railscasts episode above, just for note : you can't use select within includes :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you not take your example from this blog post, which very clearly explains the differences and similarities between `joins` and `includes`? Quite the coincidence if not.

http://nlingutla.com/blog/2013/04/21/includes-vs-joins-in-rails/

Comment: yes i already read it, but i still have a problem to understand joins method :)

Comment: just need to know if Post.joins(:user).select("posts.*, user.*") is equivalent to Post.includes(:user)